# How to set the User-Agent in UIWebView(IOS5)

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsuserdefaults, user-agent

The only way I have find is:

```
NSDictionary*dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"my user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

It is work well.But the only problem is that we can't modify the User-Agent later in the program.
Did anybody can solve this problem or have some other way to set the User-Agent in UIWebView?
What I want to do is set the User-Agent in UIWebView freely in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with this a while back. It is more about the timing than the actual value set. It takes time for it to cycle around and update any changes. The default value needs to be changed/set very early in the application. Like in -applicationDidFinishLoading. Any changes after that may need a bit before the changes will get picked up.

This method does work, but if you set it or change it, then try to load a webview right away, it won't always pick it up.

You can try setting the new values on the main thread and allowing it to finish before trying to load anything new... that might help.

Comment: In the program when I call the function again, to change the UserAgent to something else, UIWebView's do not update. In order to successfully update the UserAgent I need to remove/release the UIWebView and alloc/show it again.Is there any way to update the UserAgent without having to create a new UIWebView in order to have it take effect?

Comment: It is probably unlikely that you will be able to redraw the webview without either refreshing the content or instantiating a new webview. I would personally experiment with the worst case scenario and work your way back to see what will actually work.